# Submitting ID of object-populated h:selectOneMenu still causes conversion error

Tags: jsf, converters, selectonemenu

I populated my selectOneMenu with objects and trying to send the id (in itemValue) back to my bean from the selected item, I tried it using the below functionality but I keep getting error about a null converter (Which I'm trying to avoid by sending the id to my bean).

xhtml:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.id}">          
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.objectList}" var="f" itemValue="#{f.id}" itemLabel="#{f.name}" />                          
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.function}" value="OK"/>
</h:form>
```

bean:

```
private Collection<Object> objectList; //Object is an example, It is not the real class that is used
private int id;

public void function() {
    // place where id is needed.
}

// id getters & setters
```

Comment: do you have all the getters and setters of objectList, id .. etc

Comment: yes, all getters/setters are included.

Comment: The value for selectItems is set to #{f.id} but collection contains Objects and Object does not have a property 'id'.

Comment: @kaos exactly, you need to change the object type into your custom class elements

Comment: @kaos let me write an answer over this after your permission

Comment: I used 'object' as an example, the real object (user) has a property id.

Comment: @Meirav Leibowitz go ahead

Comment: can you post the exception

Comment: I'm getting no error-log in netbeans. Only after pressing on the commandButton a list-item shows up on the same page: Conversion Error setting value '' for 'null Converter'.

Answer (score 0):

The collection you are using:

```
private Collection<Object> objectList;
```

Has a plain object as the class type for its elements.

You need to change it to:

```
private Collection<MyCustomClassElement> objectList;
```

Where `MyCustomClassElement` is the class for your collection elements used in the select.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote before: I used 'object' as an example, the real object (user) has a property id.

Answer (score -2):

I think the value is not updated, use ajax to update the value once you select it...

```
<h:form id="forms">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="beanid"  value="#{bean.id}">          
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.objectList}" var="f" itemValue="#{f.id}" itemLabel="#{f.name}" />
        <f:ajax event="change" render="forms" />                  
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:commandButton action="#{bean.function}" value="OK"/>
</h:form>
```